# How to access files with Meteor 1.3 using the 'local-filesystem' URL prefix on iOS

Tags: cordova, meteor, wkwebview

As per the Meteor v1.3 [release notes](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/History.md) the [webapp plugin](https://github.com/meteor/cordova-plugin-meteor-webapp) can serve local files via the special `local-filesystem` URL prefix.

> The plugin now allows for local file access on both iOS and Android,
> using a special URL prefix
> (`http://localhost:<port>/local-filesystem/<path>`).

I am trying to access images on iOS in the `/Documents/imgcache` folder using `/local-filesystem/Documents/imagecache/someguid.png` as placed there by [imgcache.js](https://github.com/chrisben/imgcache.js) but a 404 is returned.

Where is the local-filesystem root please? How can I access the files as [cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine) as used by Meteor 1.3 does not appear to support `file://` nor `cdvfile://` URLs.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the root is in fact the filesystem root. Unfortunately I don't have a device to test on but using the simulator the correct URL path turned out to be:

```
local-filesystem/Users/username/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/device-id/data/Containers/Data/Applications/application-id/Documents/imgcache/someguid.png
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I agree, it's the filesystem root, but you don't need the http stuff at the front, it just gets in the way.

I set my image source to be this, and it works like a charm (on Meteor 1.4.3):

```
<img src="/local-filesystem/mnt/internal_sd/Android/data/com.project.my/mugshot-sNpESnqWKzKLjhaJM.png">
```